# cider-eval-buffer breaks when a function definition is void

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I have this issue in Emacs - I run `cider-eval-buffer` and one of my function definitions are void which results in an error (or multiple). I correct the error and run the command again only to get `Lisp nesting exceeds 'max-lisp-eval-depth'`. I can manually evaluate pieces of code via `C-x C-e` or `C-M-x` but I cannot run `cider-eval-buffer` again or re-evaluate the namespace I am working in. Any thoughts?

Comment: Case closed [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/455), saying this works with latest master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm cider's maintainer. Please, report this as a bug [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider), together with some example code that can be used to reproduce the error and your cider & emacs versions.

Comment: Thank you, I posted it (hopefully correctly, did it the first time).